# How to add custom azure metrics with SMS notifications?

Tags: c#, azure

I work with Azure and now I want to add SMS notification in specific cases.

It works good when I use Log-based metrics, but I want to create notification on specific exception.

The flow in the next one: exception is thrown => Azure knows to recognize it => Azure sends SMS about it.

Can you tell me where can I create it and how to integrate code exception into Azure logic?

Thank you!

Comment: What resource is throwing the exception? A logic app may not be necessary as part of the flow if you use Azure Mionitor + Alerts

Comment: MVC project, class that responsible for SQL connection.

Comment: I mean where is the project hosted, on what Azure resource? An app service, docker container, etc?

Comment: App Service, regular one

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a custom exception:

```
public class MySqlException : Exception 
{
    public MySqlException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

You can create a `Log Analytics` query to find those exceptions in a given timestamp:

```
exceptions
| where ['type'] == "MySqlException"
| where timestamp > ago(5m)
```

Now create an alert rule from log analytics:

[image: create alert rule Azure]

Add in the threshold amount, in this case I've added 1. With this configuration we'll fire our `Action` every time an alert is thrown within a 5 minute window:

[image]

Next, click on `Actions` at the bottom, this is where we'll configure the SMS:

[image]

You'll likely need to create an `Action Group` if this is your first time setting up `Azure Alerts`:

[image]

Once created you'll be able to set up your SMS, the blade will automatically load. Under `Notification Type` select Email/SMS message/Push/Voice`:

[image]

Then the blade on the right will open to configure your SMS options, such as phone number. Tick `SMS (Carrier charges may apply)` and input your details:

[image]

I'll not post my phone number on StackOverflow :)

Click save, then give your `Notification Type` a name:

[image]

Then save your action group:

[image]

Return back to your `Create an Alert Rule` blade to apply your action group creation:

[image]

Click `Add action groups` and select the group you just created, then `OK`. The blade should update to look similar to mine:

[image]

Then click `Review and Create`:

[image]

Now you'll receive an SMS whenever `MySqlException` is thrown!

If you need more granular checks in your alert, such as a specific `App Service` throwing the exception you can make those changes and update the rule without too much trouble.

If you want to then review the `Alert` you created it's easy to find again:

[image]

Comment: You wrote so detailed answer. Thank you!
For some reason I can't create an alert rule, the function disabled for me

Comment: Do you have the correct access rights in your subscription to be able to create one?